# Python win32 console program can hang depending on memory usage

Tags: python, memory, console

I am having problems with a Python routine that creates a data structure of linked objects and then hangs, sometimes for ever.

If I create small data structures (e.g., for testing the code), there are no issues. However, larger structures can cause them to hang.

I have various sized scripts running in a win32 console that either hang for a minute or so, or hang indefinitely, depending on the size of the data structure created. Using Windows Task Manager, the memory associated with a script that hangs for a while and then finishes is about 25 M bytes, whereas the script that hangs forever is about 50 M bytes.

Typing CTRL-C terminates the hanging scripts immediately. The scripts have actually finished executing all instructions (i.e. a print statement at the end has been seen on the console), but they just hang.

Can anyone suggest how to debug this problem?

It is clearly related to the size (amount) of the data, because the more data, the longer it takes for Python to hang up (i.e., return). So, I guess it is memory related. But it is not actually causing a fault: somehow Python just does not manage to release the memory if the data structure gets too big.

Comment: Can you show more details/code about the data structure? Will be helpful in giving more specific advice.

Comment: Are scripts running as different threads or subtasks? Is so, it would seem likely that you are not terminating them correctly when they are complete and you run into resource starvation. If not, I am sure I can think of any non-generic advice, i.e., add logging, make sure you don't silently eat exceptions, etc., run in a debugger and interrupt execution once the program hangs to see what code is running.

Comment: Seems obvious, but should mention that when it is hanging and responds to a ^C, you should also get a stack trace that should give you some idea of the code that it running when hung. When hung is the CPU maxed (or at least once core), and is it near 0 percent CPU -- tells you whether running in a tight loop and is is blocking on and I/O, socket, resource, etc.

Comment: I should have explained in the OP that there is no stack trace after CTRL-C, because the script has finished executing the Python code. That is why I don't know where to look for the problem (hence, no code to show). 

Furthermore, when hanging, the Task Manager shows that one core is maxed out (25%) for a while, but then that activity subsides to 0. 

I should also explain that the problem only arises when I read the data needed to initialise my data structure from files (and I need to un-pickle it). So I suspect that there is some IO related aspect to the problem. 

No threading is involved.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but I have used cProfile to see if I could identify a problem. I imported the whole module like this `cProfile.run('import specs')`. But sadly, the report is generated after 1.4 seconds and then the console just hangs, as per usual.

Comment: Problem solved! I did not know that when Python is executing a destructor (`__del__` method) a stack trace will not be generated after pressing CTRL-C. 

My problem is that the clean up of a number of objects (`__del__` method of my container) was becoming slower as the total number of objects grew. I could not see that until I printed a report from the `__del__` method! 

Thanks for the suggestions :-)